# Как отключить метод в самом методе vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня есть кнопка, которая должна отключаться при определенном условии:

```
//Кнопка добавления
    add() {
      if (this.noMoreThanOne() === false) {
        const currentTicker = {
          name: this.ticker,
          price: '-'
        }
        this.tickers.push(currentTicker)
        this.ticker = ''
      } else if (this.ticker.length === '' || this.noMoreThanOne() === true) {
        this.ticker = false
      }
    }
```

Можно ли в место строки `this.tikcer = false` прописать отключение метода add()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В секции computed добавьте функцию addEnabled(), в которой пропишите логику, а в add() проверяйте: if(this.addEnabled){...

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/827319)

Comment: Не согласен. Я как раз описал способ отключения метода add().